# How to close file that has been read

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

So im trying to close a file (transactions.txt) that has been open that i've used to read into a textbox and now I want to save back to the file but the problem debug says that the file is in use so I need to find a way to close it. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

```
        SearchID = textBox1.Text;
        string ID = SearchID.ToString();
        bool idFound = false;
        int count = 0;

        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("transactions.txt"))
        {

            //listView1.Items.Add(line);

            if (line.Contains(ID))
            {
                idFound = true;
            }

            //Displays Transactions if the variable SearchID is found.
            if (idFound && count < 8)
            {
                textBox2.Text += line + "\r\n";
                count++;

            }
        }
    }

    private void SaveEditedTransaction()
    {
        SearchID = textBox1.Text;
        string ID = SearchID.ToString();
        bool idFound = false;
        int count = 0;

        foreach (var lines in File.ReadLines("transactions.txt"))
        {

            //listView1.Items.Add(line);

            if (lines.Contains(ID))
            {
                idFound = true;
            }

            if (idFound)
            {
                string edited = File.ReadAllText("transactions.txt");
                edited = edited.Replace(lines, textBox2.Text);
                File.WriteAllText("Transactions.txt", edited);
            }
```

Comment: Why are you reading multiple times from the same file (`File.ReadLines("transactions.txt")` and  `File.ReadAllText("transactions.txt")`)?

Comment: because thats where the information I need to pull from is. I take a transaction from the file, edit it in the text box and then save it back into the file.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that `File.ReadLines` keeps the file open while you read it, since you've put the call to write new text to it *inside* the loop, the file is still open.

Instead I would simply break out of the loop when you find the id, and then put the if-statement that writes to the file outside the loop.

This, however, means that you will also need to maintain which line to replace in.

So actually, instead I would switch to using `File.ReadAllLines`. This reads the entire file into memory, and closes it, before the loop starts.

Now, pragmatic minds might argue that if you have a lot of text in that text file, `File.ReadLines` (that you're currently using) will use a lot less memory than `File.ReadAllLines` (that I am suggesting you should use), but if that's the case then you should switch to a database, which would be much more suited to your purpose anyway. It is, however, a bit of an overkill for a toy project with 5 lines in that file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `StreamReader` directly with the `using` statement, for example:

```
var lines = new List<string>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\test.txt")) {
    var line = reader.ReadLine();

    while (line != null) {
        lines.Add(line);
        line = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

By using the `using` statement the `StreamReader` instance will automatically be disposed of after it's done with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    "transactions.txt",
    File.ReadAllLines("transactions.txt")
        .Select(x => x.Contains(ID) ? textBox2.Text : x));
```

It works fine, but if the file is big you have to find other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StreamReader class instead of the methods of the File class. In this way you can use, Stream.Close() and Stream.Dispose().