# Does File.ReadLines(filePath).First() close the file immediately?

Tags: c#, .net, file, enumerable

I know that when using the `IEnumerable` returned by `File.ReadLines()` in a `foreach` loop, the file gets closed automatically after the loop.
I just need to quickly check the first line of a file. Is this enough or will it keep the file open?

```
protected void Append(string filePath, Encoding encoding)
{
    try
    {
        string firstLine = File.ReadLines(filePath, encoding).First();
        // more code here
    }
    catch
    {
        // more code here
    }
}
```

Comment: @paulsm4 that's `File.ReadAllLines()`, but `File.ReadLines()` *does* keep the file open until the iterator is disposed.

Comment: source code publicly available https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ReadLinesIterator.cs,e55db6d3fed9e8eb

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504528/how-to-close-file-that-has-been-read#:~:text=ReadAllLines%20.,lot%20less%20memory%20than%20File.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>(Note that this is for `File.ReadLines()` which returns an `IEnumerable<String>` - this is not for `File.ReadAllLines()` which returns a `String[]`.)</sub>

---

> Does `File.ReadLines(filePath).First()` close the file immediately?

### Yes

...assuming by "immediately" you mean when the *entire statement* completes - not just the inner `ReadLines()` sub-expression.

---

- Internally, `File.ReadLines()` returns an [instance of `ReadLinesIterator`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/ReadLinesIterator.cs) - which is an `IEnumerable<T>`.
- When an `IEnumerable<T>` is iterated-over, C#/.NET uses `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator<T>()` which returns an `IEnumerator<T>` which **must** be disposed after the program has finished iterating what it wants.

  - Because `IEnumerator<T>` instances **must** be disposed you're always encouraged to use `foreach` which handles this for you (instead of manually handling an `IEnumerator<T>` yourself).

    - `foreach` will also ensure the `IEnumerator<T>` is disposed if an exception is thrown inside the `foreach` loop body.
- In this specific case `ReadLinesIterator` contains a `StreamReader` (which contains the open `FileStream`). When the `ReadLinesIterator` is disposed the internal `StreamReader` is closed, which in-turn closes the `FileStream`.
- The `.Frist()` method is Linq's `Enumerable.First( IEnumerable<T> source )`.

  - Internally, Linq's `First()` does the same thing as calling `foreach( T item in source )` and returning immediately inside the foreach - so the `First` method will dispose of the `ReadLinesIterator` for you.

---

#### Safety

I note that `ReadLinesIterator` [is both an `IEnumerator<T>` *and* an `IEnumerable<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Iterator.cs) and it wraps an open `StreamReader` - which does mean that you do need to be careful when using `ReadLines()` to ensure that the `IEnumerable<T>` you see is actually iterated-over, otherwise you do risk leaking open file handles.

...this also means that if you're using a Linq method chain and an exception happens inside the Linq chain *but outside* any of Linq's internal `try/catch`/`foreach`/`using` blocks then you will leak an file handle that won't be closed until the GC finalizes the `ReadLinesIterator`... though I admit I struggle to think of when this could happen.

Comment: The question was closed as a duplicate. I don't think the alleged duplicate explains this matter in the detail you do. I was especially interested in how the Linq method First() will affect the file, which definitely wasn't inferable from the claimed duplicate. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`File.ReadLines` returns `IEnumerable<string>`. Enumerable uses `IEnumerator<string>` to read lines, which is disposable.

Correct way to read first line and be resource-safe:

```cs
var lines = File.ReadLines(path);
string firstLine;
using (var it = lines.GetEnumerator())
{
    if (!it.MoveNext())
        throw new InvalidOperationException("File is empty");
    firstLine = it.Current;
}

UseLine(firstLine);
```

It's complicated but safe for sure

Comment: Your code does **the exact same thing** that `ReadLines().First()` does.

Comment: Just read your comment and opened source, and it disposes. I wasn't expecting this. You're right

Answer (score 0):

Best practice id to read file using stream reader.

```
var lines = new List<string>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\test.txt")) {
    var line = reader.ReadLine();

    while (line != null) {
        lines.Add(line);
        line = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Once the code move out of using statement, fill object will be disposed and wfile will be closed. File.ReadLines never closes the file.

Comment: `File.ReadLines` - it does when the returned enumerator is disposed - which `foreach` does for you.

Comment: I disagree that your approach is "best practices" - you're buffering every line in-memory inside an expanding list - which is doing the same thing as `File.ReadAllLines`. This approach will waste memory if you only want to process lines in isolation.

Comment: @Dai The approach is for reading and closing file.

Comment: @Amit But I just wanted the quickest and safest way to only read the first line, as the file is huge.